# "Unknown error" while trying to run MSOpenTech redis server

Tags: redis, server, redis-server

I'm new to redis and I've basically just installed it and try to run redis server with default config, but each time I get the same error:

```
[9108] 16 Jun 19:56:50.018 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379:
bind: Unknown error
```

It's an MSOpenTech release. No matter what version I use I get the same error.

what could it be? And how can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty. I haven't figured out what caused the problem, probably my 6379 port was used. Or it could be some kind of bug (because it still use port 6379 for listening...)

Anyway, it started working when I changed the port to run Redis on during the installation to 8000.

P.S. It turned out that it can't listen to the port which is set to run Redis. Probably that's why they were set the same by default. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an error. in case of windows, I specify configuration file on CMD.

> redis-server redis.windows.conf

and It worked.